# How can I show that span(W1 ∩ W2) ⊂ span(W1) ∩ span(W2)?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that span(W1 ∩ W2) ⊂ span(W1) ∩ span(W2) for any subsets W1 and W2 of V? so the span of a set of vectors is the set of all linear combinations of the vectors, so some scalars multiplied by them subsets?

Comment: This is a proof by grammar.  If something is a combination of vectors from $W_1 \cap W_2$, then it is certainly a combination of vectors from $W_1$....

Answer (score 1):

$Span(W_1\cap W_2)$ is the smallest vector space that contain $W_1\cap W_2$. Since $W_1\cap W_2$ is included in $Span(W_1)\cap Span(W_2),$ then so is $Span(W_1\cap W_2)$.